# Verification step for mostly-off-topic tags?

Tags: feature-request, tags, asking-questions, ask-question-wizard

A substantial portion of questions on [grub](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/grub), [uefi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/uefi), [efi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/efi) and [bios](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bios) are "I upgraded my OS, and now my computer won't boot".

Would it be possible (/useful) to add an extra verification step for questions on tags that have a *lot* of off-topic questions, suggesting StackExchange sites relevant for non-programming questions on the specific topic?

Comment: By *extra verification step*, do you mean another popup or interstitial? Because let's be honest here, people with unbootable computers will probably not even bother reading it.

Comment: For people who want to VTC: [grub](http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=[grub]%20closed%3ano) [uefi](http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=[uefi]%20closed%3ano) [efi](http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=[efi]%20closed%3ano) [bios](http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=[bios]%20closed%3ano)

Comment: Well, or just a tickbox with an error-message (with suggestions) if it isn't ticked.

Comment: This is called a [tag warning](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/354934/3750257)