# What determines what tags will get a popup with usage guidance?

Tags: support, tags, tag-tips

Related: [Display a popup when a low-reputation user tags a question with a frequently-misused tag](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/347903/display-a-popup-when-a-low-reputation-user-tags-a-question-with-a-frequently-mis)

So, awhile back I had a [proposal](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/347903/display-a-popup-when-a-low-reputation-user-tags-a-question-with-a-frequently-mis) to show a popup when users add a frequently-misused tag to their question.

Recently, when I went to use the [seo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/seo) tag, I got this popup:
[image]

I noticed a similar one for tagging burnination requests on Meta awhile back.

I'm curious about the details of how this works. What determines what tags will receive a popup like this? Which tags have it now? Who writes the text? Is there any way for the community to curate this (i.e. determine what the text is like you do for tag wikis, nominate tags for receiving this popup, etc.), or is it currently a manual process done by staff and/or moderators?

If it's currently a manual process, are there any plans for allowing some kind of community curation for this? If not, would it be worthwhile to create a feature request for that?

Comment: I think it's cute that you believe low-reputation users heed (or even read) warnings.

Comment: @Jeeped No, I lost that illusion a long time ago, I just think that making it more obvious that they're violating site rules might deter at least some of the behavior.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

These are called 'tag warnings' and they are added manually. A similar question was asked on Meta Stack Exchange, and recent new tag warnings usually follows these steps:

- First, somebody needs to realize that a lot of [xyz](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/xyz) questions share a common problem that *might* be prevented/mitigated by a tag warning.
- Somebody posts a Meta question proposing the tag warning. [Here](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7358/22219) is a recent example from another site.
- The community can vote on the proposal and suggest changes to the wording.
- When there is enough and near-unanimous support for the change, a ♦ moderator can contact a Community Manager to have the tag warning implemented.

I don't think there is a complete list with tags having warnings. We could make one from collective knowledge, or wait for a Stack Overflow employee to pull it from the codebase/database.

Comment: @Braiam does 'usually a ♦ moderator' not imply by itself that it's an option for normal users as well?

Comment: Because, statistically speaking, moderators don't actually know which tags would benefit more of these warnings. Also, it's irrelevant who brings the issue up. Anyone can and should do it, nobody should wait a moderator because the are "usually" the ones who does.

Comment: So where is there a list of the ones that already have warnings? Is there a footnote on the hover-tag-description? Do we have to searchmeta for a previous request? Do we have to create a one-repper account to test?

Comment: @Jeeped there's no such list (that I'm aware of). You can try to search Meta (don't forget Meta Stack Exchange, some older requests could be buried there as well). That's why I hope an SO employee comes along :)