# Confusion between [appscript] and [google-apps-script]

Tags: support, tags, retag-request, tag-disambiguation

#### Issue:

*The [appscript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/appscript) tag is meant to be used for Apple Scripts, but due to confustion on the part of users, most questions under this tag are in fact Google Apps Script questions.*

#### More Information:

As per the [appscript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/appscript) tag description:

> In this context, Appscript is a high-level, user-friendly Apple event bridge that allows you to control scriptable Mac OS X applications from Python, Ruby and Objective-C. Appscript makes these languages serious alternatives to Apple's own AppleScript language for automating your Mac.

The issue is that, colloquially, the phrase 'Apps Script' is much more synonymous with Google Apps Script—Google's JavaScript-based, cloud-based scripting language. In the last two weeks alone, I personally have changed [almost 20 questions](https://pastebin.com/KwiZiHih) erroneously tagged [appscript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/appscript) when [google-apps-script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-apps-script) is what the question was really about.

#### Question:

***What can be done about this?***

It's quite clear that the warning given at the beginning of the [appscript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/appscript) tag description:

> Use only for Apple scripts, not google-apps-script.

is not good enough, especially for new users. In a lot of cases, if it weren't for users like me specifically checking the [appscript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/appscript) tag for these erroneously-tagged questions, issues are getting buried in the depths of incorrect tag pages.

On top of this, the last correctly-tagged, genuine Appscript question was on [July 28th](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/appscript), almost 3 months prior to this post.

I'm not suggesting to make [appscript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/appscript) a synonym of [google-apps-script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-apps-script). Conversely, neither am I suggesting we ***don't*** make these synonymous. But more clarity is definitely needed, because these are wildly differing tags which are way too closely named.

Comment: This is a pretty intractable problem, and not at all limited to this specific case. I'm not sure what we can do to address it. Maybe adding [a tag warning](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/354934) or some [usage guidance](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/274632) would be a start. A staff member would be required for that; it's not something moderators can do. And all that'll do is make the admonition at the beginning of the tag wiki excerpt more visible. It can't make people follow it.

Comment: `This is a pretty intractable problem` Agreed. I am aware that there is no way of making people follow a specification set out in a tag description, but sometihng like a tag warning would certainly be of help. I would not be surprised if this isn't the only tag ambiguity that exists on Stack, but I think that's all the more of a reason for us to come up with additional steps and/or guidence for users to mitigate at least some of the erroneousness in tagging.

Comment: This is still something that I have had to keep on top of for question organisation - another 8 questions from the last week or so all erroneously tagged, with the latest genuine `appscript` question July 28th. The lack of genuine questions regarding Apple Scripts makes me wonder if this tag is needed for it at all when it is so ambiguous to new users.

Comment: 9 months later: [related discussion](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216782/discussion-between-ruben-and-themaster). There is an additional argument in favour of the proposal - it is no longer supported. @CodyGray - they are multiplying at an alarming rate, one more while I was writing the comment and reatagging another question... Every question since June is actually about [tag:google-apps-script] Please, we need to put a blow of merci on the tag - maybe rename to [tag:apple-appscript] for now?

Comment: Besides the tags used for them, *appscript* and *Apple Script*  aren't the same programming language.

Comment: Instead of [tag:apple-appscript] it might be better [tag:sourceforge-appscript] because appscript was is not an Apple product but it's hosted in Sourceforge. Related https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/399042/1595451

Comment: @CodyGray - could you please take a look at the request for appscript tag changes? We think that a rename to [tag:sourceforge-appscript] should do the trick to disambiguate and avoid mistagging. See [TheMaster's post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/399089/11407695) here and [Rubén's proposal](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/399042/11407695) for details. Thank you!

Comment: @CodyGray - pinging again just in case the request has been buried under the avalanche of other notifications. Could you (or Bhargav) take another look at the ratagging of the [tag:appscript] - renaming to [tag:sourceforge-appscript] seems like a bulletproof solution that hopefully everyone can agree upon.

Comment: Retagged from [tag:discussion] to [tag:support] as We have clear consensus.

Answer (score 4):

### Current Data:

- The [appscript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/appscript) tag currently has a total of 61 questions and 0.3k watchers
- The [google-apps-script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-apps-script) tag has a total of 33,633 questions  and 6.4k watchers
- [appscript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/appscript) was  removed and [google-apps-script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-apps-script) was added to the question a total of 644 times[<sup>SEDE</sup>](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/revision/1263087/1555494/how-many-questions-associated-with-tag1-was-changed-to-tag2)
- The [applescript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/applescript) tag currently has a total of 7,568 questions. The tag [applescript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/applescript) targets *AppleScript*, a scripting language created by Apple and is  different from [appscript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/appscript), which is a source-forge alternative.

### Insights:

- **[appscript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/appscript) was retagged as [google-apps-script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-apps-script)  almost 10 times than the number of questions it currently has.(644 vs 61)[<sup>SEDE</sup>](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/revision/1263087/1555494/how-many-questions-associated-with-tag1-was-changed-to-tag2)**. This is relevant because

  - Most users believe apps script simply refers to Google apps script and use the tag to refer to the same and it's a burden on the editors to change it repeatedly.
- **<sup>★New★</sup>The last valid question about [appscript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/appscript) was in March 2020. It's been almost 5 months. Almost all questions after that was renamed to [google-apps-script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-apps-script)**
- [google-apps-script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-apps-script) is 433 times more popular than [appscript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/appscript) by number of questions asked and 19 times by number of watchers. Popularity  is relevant because

  - More users frequent the popular tags and retagging  incorrectly tagged questions is efficient rather than if it was the other way around.
- [appscript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/appscript) [support ended in 2012](http://appscript.sourceforge.net/status.html). In contrast, [google-apps-script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-apps-script),  is currently in development with near monthly updates[<sup>Release History</sup>](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/releases).
- [google-apps-script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-apps-script) trend:
  [image]
  [Data](https://gist.github.com/tanaikech/fd7dbc6d630fd0550c32159635cecc96)  from [Tanaike](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/7108653/tanaike)
- [appscript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/appscript) trend:
  [image]
  [Data](https://gist.github.com/tanaikech/66d174aab293076dad3bc4b8c5842e09) from [Tanaike](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/7108653/tanaike)
- 0 questions that were tagged [appscript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/appscript) were retagged as [applescript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/applescript). So, users don't seem to  relate sourceforge-appscript to applescript or applescript tag users don't bother removing the appscript tag.

### Conclusion:

Given these stats, It is in the best interest of tag editors, moderators and all of the Stack overflow community to:

- Rename [appscript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/appscript) (only 61 questions affected) to a  specific name like [sourceforge-appscript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sourceforge-appscript). See [proposal](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/399042)
- Create [apps-script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/apps-script)/[appsscript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/appsscript) to be a synonym of [google-apps-script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-apps-script), if needed.

---

#### Update:

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

- Manual retagging of [appscript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/appscript) to [sourceforge-appscript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sourceforge-appscript) by community complete.

Comment: `appscript` --> From http://appscript.sourceforge.net/ "Appscript is a high-level, user-friendly Apple event bridge that allows you to control scriptable Mac OS X applications from Python, Ruby and Objective-C. Appscript makes these languages serious alternatives to Apple's own AppleScript language for automating your Mac."

Comment: `AppleScript` -> From https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AppleScript, "AppleScript is a scripting language created by Apple Inc. "

Comment: @Rubén Thank you. I have edited my answer to remove the confusion. Feel free to directly edit my answer, if needed.

Comment: seems like we have more or less a consesus on what should be done with the tag to minimize harm and finally close the issue? Wanted to ping Tanaike, but you seem to have done that - thank you. Also: there are two language-specific versions of the tag: [tag:py-appscript] and [tag:rb-appscript] that would be great to cross-update (well... create) wikis for once the change is done

Comment: @OlegValter We have a consensus. Not sure what more needs to be done to bring about the change. About py- and rb-, both have around 20 questions with the last question in 2014 and 2015 respectively.  Both has no relation to apps script and will not be misunderstood. I wouldn't bother with the wikis.PS: Thank you for the sede query script.

Comment: @TheMaster Well, now all we need is a diamond mod who agrees with the reasoning (from previous experience the tagging is usually handled by Cody Gray). Agreed on the lang-specific tags. PS: don't mention - I wish I could incorporate the removal stats in a more versatile version of it, but the query starts to timeout on aggregates

Comment: @OlegValter I wonder if we can rename appscript to apps-script or appsscript(two s) during the process. As long as appscript doesn't exist, it shouldn't be a problem. Or would it be better to add synonyms after the retag?

Comment: @TheMaster - probably not? It seems like the author(s) called the language Appscript with single "s" (I must admit that caused me to lookup the reference nearly every time I mention it)... Re:synonyms - I would say after retag (once we know how it is changed)

Comment: @TheMaster - whoever created the Appscript project I mean (don't have a clue who, though). Double "s" would also split the naming convention from lang-specific tags.

Comment: Ah, I think I misinterpreted your comment above. Yes, double "s" sounds like a good idea once the original tag is renamed, especially considering [the search results](https://www.google.com/search?q=apps+script&rlz=1C1CHZL_ruRU774RU774&oq=Apps+Scri&aqs=chrome.0.69i59j69i57j0j69i60l3j69i65l2.5723j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8). Synonymizing "appsscript" to the main [tag:google-apps-script] tag can be even done anytime, as far as I know

Comment: @OlegValter Edited my answer to  directly support ruben's proposal. That will be the best way to move forward.

Comment: Thank you - we can all probably rest our case and wait on the decision. Fun fact I overlooked - the tag *was* briefly used as a Google Apps Script synonym in 2013, but I cannot find any discussion on what happened (apart from Mogsdad's ref to a migration of GAS questions).

Comment: @OlegValter Interesting. I think he did it manually(without discussion). There should have been  less than 20 questions in his time. He  probably retagged all questions to google-apps-script and proposed the migration by a direct tag edit. Since it had to be approved, He probably got less than 20k reps at the time..

Answer (score 2):

The tag appscript shouldn't exist. That's intractable. The potential for misuse is there. No amount of babysitting would be as effective. Just replace the tag for unambiguous ones.

Comment: Braiam, that's also a solution - so long as we finally do something about it... One thing that stops me from saying "all for it" is that up to 2013 it had valid questions - if it is sent into oblivion, what to do with those questions? It can partially be curcumvented by chnaging to language-specific versions (it had Python, Ruby and Objective-C versions, two of which are represented by tags, only Objective-C lacks one). Also it had tools that are not specific to any language. Rubén has a good idea how to disambiguate with  the least potential for abuse in the related thread, I think

Comment: @OlegValter we made an error before. We've making these kinds of errors thinking that no one, ever, would use the same name for their products. Naming isn't a programmers  forte as we all know, so we could have fixed it back then.

Comment: Braiam, I agree, and as someone who is primarily active in GAS tag, I would love to see it just quitely go away (that was quite a naming mishap)... Just voicing my concern about the issues that might arise if the tag is simply deleted. Well, after all, the decision will likely to fall on Cody, so the more we flesh out the possibilities - the better

Answer (score 1):

**Overview**

The issue is surprizingly resilient and even outlived the language it represented. Even a Google and DuckDuckGo search on "appscript" returns [results (Google)](https://www.google.com/search?q=appscript) / [results (DuckDuckGo)](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=appscript) for Google Apps Script. The tag continues to cause confusion, both with **AppleScript** and **Google Apps Script** which both have prominent tags.

To summarize, the tag:

1. Causes confusion with [google-apps-script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-apps-script) (no correctly tagged questions for a long time)
2. Has a potential to be [confused with AppScript](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/appscript/id1038108795) (healthcare app)
3. Has a potential to be confused with [applescript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/applescript)
4. Language development and support [stopped in 2012](http://appscript.sourceforge.net/status.html)

**Activity graph**

The [tag activiy](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1261578/questions-posted-with-a-tag#graph) flatlined, and the only questions tagged with it now are incorrect ( see [2020-07-16](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62913951/appscript-write-data-from-googles-spreadsheet-to-firebase-realtimedb) ):

[image: tag activity graph for 5 years]

**Proposal**

1. *Current consensus is*: merge [appscript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/appscript) into [sourceforge-appscript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sourceforge-appscript)

> 1. Old alternative: rename [appscript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/appscript) into [apple-appscript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/apple-appscript)

2. Retag [appscript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/appscript) questions to [google-apps-script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-apps-script) in the meantime (after all, we do it regardless)
3. Make the [appscript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/appscript) a synonym of the [google-apps-script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-apps-script) tag (not necessarily after step 2)

Comment: @Rubén - yes, seems like it (at least its sourceforge page says so). The support and development stopped in 2012. To cite: "Please note that appscript is no longer developed or supported, and its use is not recommended for new projects". I found it ironic that the tag causes confusion long after the project stopped existing (or do you know that it is still alive in some form?)

Comment: Thanks (I should continued reading). Few days ago I found docs about appscript...

Comment: No worries. It would be nice if we could get the tag for GAS - I've been going through the questions tagged with [tag:appscript] recently and found that I missed a lot of them because I did not watch the tag...

Comment: Popularity / lack of official support are not arguments to "hijack" a tag but harm done might be. Is [tag:appscript] causing any harm?

Comment: @Rubén - true, these are only secondary arguments that say that *we* are likely to not cause harm. Re:causing harm. I don't know - is a tag harmful when all of the questions for the last year that are tagged with it are tagged incorrectly? +a lot of them are not tagged with [tag:google-apps-script]

Comment: Are there any dispute regarding removing [tag:appscript] from questions about Google Apps Script or is this easily handled by community members having enough rep to propose / do edits?

Comment: @Rubén - as far as I understand there is none. One could say there is even a silent consensus. The tag itself contains a usage note "Use only for Apple scripts, NOT google-apps-script". Just that Rafa's suggestion did not get much attention initially after Cody expressed initial concern (see first comment under the question)

Comment: Maybe we should fix the note (as currently there Apple Scripts is another programming language)

Comment: @Rubén - would love to as an easy to do solution, but that does not stop people from slapping it onto questions :)  I think a retag, rename, then synonymize will, though. And even if a small portion will get to Apple folks, I would argue they will know what to do with the question. As I mentioned in chat, just yesterday I pointed that out to a user that consistently tagged their questions with it: there was a genuine surprize despite the plead in the tag excerpt. The visibility of these warnings is very low (and the tag is autosuggested when you type app-script or appscript..

Comment: ...which, given that I noticed that people usually think that GAS is "Google App Scripts", it is understandable why the confusion arose in the first place)

Answer (score 0):

As of August 14th, 2020, [appscript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/appscript) no longer exists. For further details see [Rename [appscript] → [sourceforge-appscript]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/399042/1595451)