# Rename [appscript] → [sourceforge-appscript]

Tags: support, status-completed, tags, retag-request, tag-disambiguation

From http://appscript.sourceforge.net/

> **What is appscript?**
>
> > *Please note that appscript is no longer developed or supported, and its use is not recommended for new projects.*
>
> Appscript is a high-level, user-friendly Apple event bridge that allows you to control scriptable Mac OS X applications from Python, Ruby and Objective-C. Appscript makes these languages serious alternatives to Apple's own AppleScript language for automating your Mac.

Reasons to ask for this change

1. *appscript* is hosted in sourceforge -> http://appscript.sourceforge.net/
2. We already have [sourceforge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sourceforge)
3. Searching in Google and DuckDuckGo for *appscript* doesn't include results about *appscript* on the first page but include results about Google Apps Script, Apple Script, and other stuff
4. [google-apps-script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-apps-script) is confused with *appscript*
5. [applescript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/applescript) is confused with *appscript*

Benefits

This could help to prevent new users to use [appscript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/appscript) instead of [applescript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/applescript) and [google-apps-script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-apps-script) so their questions get the proper attention of followers of these tags

---

Good

- There are 29 questions having [appscript python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/appscript+python)
- There are 8 questions having [appscript ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/appscript+ruby)
- There are 4 questions havin [appscript objective-c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/appscript+objective-c)

Bad?

- There are 48 questions returned by [appscript -python -ruby -objective-c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/appscript+-objective-c+-python+-ruby)
- There aren't questions returned by [sourceforge appscript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sourceforge+appscript)

Related

- [Confusion between [appscript] and [google-apps-script]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/390701/1595451)

Comment: hm, that's a good one - it may help to avoid accidentally making [tag:applescript] being incorrectly retagged to [tag:appscript] while accomplishing the same goal - remove the confusion with [tag:google-apps-script].

Comment: That said, we would probably want a second opinion from [tag:sourceforge] guys. Is there an established practice of prefixing sourceforge- to products hosted on it? If so, it would probably be an ideal solution for disambiguating the tag

Comment: \[sourceforge*] returns only [tag:sourceforge]

Comment: Oh well... Let's wait for someone to weigh in then. Btw, I noticed that the problem might spana all tag versions: [tag:rb-appscript] is starting to become mistagged (although 2 questions is fixable, just a sec)

Comment: Re:[tag:rb-appscript] - done. [tag:py-appscript] seems unaffected, and Objective-C version does not seem to exist. That raises the question, though, that I missed initially - what would we do with [tag:py-appscript] and [tag:rb-appscript] after the rename? My bet is leave them be and update tag wiki for the renamed tag to include reference to specific tag.

Comment: I think that we should do nothing with [tag:py-appscript] and [tag:rb-appscript]

Comment: Rubén - agreed - already cleaned up the [tag:rb-appscript] a little (where questions were obviously about [tag:google-apps-script]), seem to be fine otherwise

Answer (score 1):

[sourceforge-appscript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sourceforge-appscript) was created. The tag excerpt and wiki are waiting for approval --> https://stackoverflow.com/tags/sourceforge-appscript/info