# Is there something to do with active tags which are mainly collecting non-programming questions?

Tags: discussion, tags, questions

Just came across [yocto](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/yocto) (https://www.yoctoproject.org/), then after a few clicks [bitbake](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bitbake), and the more generic [openembedded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/openembedded) and [embedded-linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/embedded-linux).
Even when these topics are going heavy-weight, they seem to discuss about configuration/make files, but often they're just about file systems, storage partitions, various USB peripherals, hardware in general, problems with working from the command line. Also with a read-the-documentation-for-me-pls vibe, as most questions are coming from new/newish users.
While yes, I'm aware of that [software tools commonly used by programmers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) are legit topics, opening the 50 most recent Yocto questions just doesn't feel like programmers dealing with programming-related problems. Less than 10% seems to be on-topic to me. It can be a me problem, but in my opinion this policy may be used too leniently here. When someone runs into a superuser or unix/linux question, that might not automatically transform into an SO one even if they happened to use a tool which no non-programmer would ever hear about.
Apparently there is/was a concept of [tag warning](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/354934/what-determines-what-tags-will-get-a-popup-with-usage-guidance), which could be used here, though I can't even find out if it still exists (random attempt to create a seo-question doesn't produce such warning to me).

I could go on a one-man crusade any time, just that's not really a lasting solution. If there's a problem at all, of course.

Comment: If the tag is collecting mostly off-topic questions then you can propose it as a burnination target.

Comment: "one-man crusade any time" - prepare for account ban :) Please do not start large scale editing/moderation actions without discussion and agreement here on meta.

Answer (score 7):

There is no problem.

Yocto is a build-your-own-custom-Linux-distro constructor set. The only people who use this tool are embedded software developers. Questions about using Yocto, BitBake, and related tools are inherently on-topic for Stack Overflow, just as questions about compilers (e.g., GCC) and IDEs (e.g., Visual Studio) are inherently on-topic for Stack Overflow.

The *vast majority* of recent questions that I see tagged [yocto](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/yocto) are absolutely on-topic for Stack Overflow. I see no evidence that these tags are collecting non-programming questions.

So, it doesn't need a tag warning, the tag doesn't need to be removed, and neither you nor anyone else should go on a crusade closing questions on that tag, because your close-votes would be inaccurate and in conflict with site policy.

> Also with a read-the-documentation-for-me-pls vibe, as most questions are coming from new/newish users.

This doesn't matter. Seriously. The only way this matters is that it makes the questions easier to answer. Stack Overflow's scope is not defined as all of the things *not* covered by the documentation. Our scope is all questions about programming topics and tools, regardless of whether they're covered by the documentation or not. If we don't already have a Q&A about that topic, and it is on-topic for Stack Overflow, then asking and answering that question are useful contributions to our knowledge base, regardless of where the answer came from or where else it might be found.

I *do* see a general issue where people are asking questions under these tags that are unclear and/or too broad because they lack sufficient background with these technologies and don't know where to begin. Probably because effectively utilizing the technologies that fall under the umbrella of these tags requires a relatively advanced understanding of hardware, kernels, and other low-level aspects of programming that *most* software developers have no knowledge of or experience with. Such questions are generally unsuitable for Stack Overflow and should be closed. However, this is, unfortunately, not a problem unique to any of these tags related to embedded development. Such questions can and should be dealt with on a case-by-case basis, not by creating friction for embedded developers who have just as much right to use Stack Overflow as a resource as any other type of developer.

Comment: *Questions about using Yocto, BitBake, and related tools are inherently on-topic for Stack Overflow* - that's the part I'm challenging, if *build-your-own-custom-Linux-distro* is programming. And yes, I explicitly mentioned that it's *a tool which no non-programmer would ever hear about*.

Comment: Then your "challenge" makes no sense whatsoever. It's been part of Stack Overflow's scope since day one, and it remains prominently in the site's [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), that questions about software tools commonly used by programmers are on-topic here. If they're software tools *exclusively* used by programmers, then there's not even any grey area or room for dispute.

Comment: It's certainly possible for a tag/topic to be on topic, and for that tag to *also* be collecting a ton of non-programming questions.